# vue custom filter error in vue test utils

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I am getting this error when running my test in vue-test-utils `this.$options.filters.customCurrency is not a function`

How can I either stub this as it's not needed or mock the function to prevent the error?

```
 Vue.filter('customCurrency', function (currency) {
    return currency
  });
```

**component.vue**

```
this.$options.filterks.customCurrency(this.currency)
```

Comment: have you found solutions? I'm having same problem

Comment: Yes, you can use this in your test file - localVue.filter('customCurrency', customCurrency);